# Time calulation for a program execution?

Tags: c

I am using the following program (which is a demo on a site) to see the time elapsed during the the execution.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #define BILLION  1000000000
 int main( int argc, char **argv )

{
    struct timespec start, stop;
    double accum;
    int val=clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&start);
    if( val==-1 ) {
        perror( "clock gettime" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

 system( argv[1] );
 if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&stop); ) {
    perror( "clock gettime" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

printf( "%lf\n", accum );

return( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

When I am executing this code I am getting  the following error

time.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
time.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to`clock_gettime'

Can you tell me why is this and what will fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link with the realtime library. Try `gcc ... -lrt`.